# Adding a red border while recording

Tags: unity-game-engine

I’m working on a feature to record the current game view and I need an idea on how to show some kind of visuals on the screen while recording (e.g., a red border around the window).

The Challenge:

The recorded images should include everything that is happening on the screen – including the current UI canvas – except for the red border.

I feel like there is an easy solution, but I just don’t see it :D I would really appreciate new ideas.

Things I have considered:

- Using ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot in a Coroutine, after a preceding WairForEndOfFrame.
  Problem: How can I show extra visuals without recording them?
- Record the src RenderTexture from OnRenderImage and add the recording border afterwards.
  Problem: This might not be the complete image I want to record. The recorded image is darker than what is shown on screen and the image might not be complete. The canvas and/or additional cameras are not included yet.
- Adding a border via a second canvas.
  Problem: How can I access and save the partial image? I mean the rendered scene + the first UI canvas but without the second UI canvas.
- Rendering the main camera on command with Camera.Render.
  Problem: This renders the main camera a second time and I wouldn’t know how to include the UI canvas.

Comment: have a second camera that shows the redbox, but doesnt show it on the normal camera where you save the picture from?